# Problems with inheritance of classes in C#

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance, class-hierarchy

I am working on a simple project and I've created a few classes that is the class diagram:

[image: diagram]

And I am writing a method ChangeContent in WordDocument.cs and I want to change the value of Size and the Compilator says that Size doesn't exist in the current content.

Can you explain me why ?

```
public abstract class BinaryDocuments : Document
{
    public ulong Size
    {
        get { throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
        set { }
    }
} 

public class WordDocuments : OfficeDocuments, IEditable
{
    public ulong NumberOfChar
    {
        get
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }

    public void ChangeContent(string newContent)
    {
        this.**Size** = 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have defined `Size` as public on the `BinaryDocuments` class.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: What is the access modifier on the `Size` property in the BinaryDocuments class? It should at least be a `protected set`.

Comment: Does `Encryptable` class actually inherit `BinaryDocuments`, or is it just an overlap in lines?

Comment: Inherits BinaryDocuments

Comment: Please edit the code into your question.

Comment: Please show the line in `WordDocument.cs` to which the error message refers to.

Comment: Why do you think the `WordDocuments` class has a `Size` property?

Comment: According to your diagram, `Encryptable` *doesn't* inherit from `BinaryDocuments`. The chain is broken.

Comment: Oh Thank you I have missed to write it!